# first steps with differentials

Tags: calculus

So i have the following exercise :

A coat of paint of thickness 0.02 in is applied to the faces of a cube whose edge is 10 in, thereby producing a slightly larger cube. Use differentials to find approximately the number of cubic inches of paint used. Also find the exact amount used by computing volumes before and after painting.

The attempt at a solution

$$ dy = 3 \cdot 10^2 \cdot 0.02 = 6 $$

However the actual solution is 12 (from the answers). Even when doing it manually :

$$ 6 \cdot 10^2 \cdot 0.02 = 12 $$

When I compute the volume before and after I get the same result as before :

$$ 10.02^3 - 10^3 = 6.012008 $$

I can clearly see that there is factor of 2 difference, but why ? I used the formula and did not get the solution, what exactly was not ok ?

Comment: For the volume computation, you're adding .02 to each side. So you need to use approximately: $10.04^3 - 10^3$, which is roughly 12.

Comment: @Christian Thank you man! I found it now :D

Comment: @gotit--thanks y = x^3 and the derivative is 3x^2. The problem was that I was equating dx to 0.02 and not to 0.04.

Comment: Ah OK.  Good that you figured it out. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

if the thickness of the paint is $0.02$, you have incremented the length of the side by $0.04$.