# Using differentials to find how much material to cover a cylinder with thickness $2cm$

Tags: calculus

I am asked the following problem:

> A cylindrical tank with no lid must have an external coating $2cm$ thick. If the internal radius is $6m$ and the height $10m$ find, using differentils, the quantity of material to do that.

I am not sure how to approach the problem. Should I consider only the variation of the radius?

\begin{align*}
V &= \pi r^2 h\\
dV &= 2 \cdot \pi \cdot r \cdot h \cdot dr\\
dV &= 2 \cdot\pi \cdot 6 \cdot 10 \cdot dr
\end{align*}

I am not sure what $dr$ is or if I tackled the problem the right way.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Recall the product rule, and both $r$ and $h$ are varying.

Comment: You've done it well so far. Remember that $dV$ stands for "change in V" and $dr$ stands for "change in r". This is, of course, an approximation that only works for small changes in $r$. We're in luck! If we let.$dr = 0.02$ then I think this should work well.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1858371/265466

Answer (score 3):

Assume that there are a solid 2 cm base and a 2 cm curved wall. Then both the height and the radius increased by 2 cm from the internal dimensions.

Using product rule,

$$\begin{align*}
V&= \pi r^2 h\\
dV &= \pi r^2\ dh + \pi h\cdot 2r\ dr\\
&= \pi6^2\cdot 0.02 + \pi 10\cdot 2\cdot6\cdot0.02\quad(\text m^3)
\end{align*}$$

This estimation is just the surface area times 0.02 m thickness.

Comment: No lid--no $dh$.

Comment: But it has a base, I suppose. If not, then $dh = 0$.

Comment: The base won't be coated either here.

Comment: @Paul that's not how I understand the quoted question, though you may be right. If the base is not coated, then there is no change in height, $dh = 0$.